# Suppose that $a \equiv b\mod m$ and that $a \equiv b\mod n $ .Assuming gcd$(m;n) = 1 $ ,prove that $a \equiv b\mod mn$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How should I approach this question? I was thinking of splitting it up such as as $ mt=b$ and $ax + ny=b$

Comment: Are the answers given not satisfactory ? If they are , consider accepting them and giving them the green tick $\color{#2f0}{\checkmark}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $a\equiv b \mod m \implies\color{#d05}{a = mk+b} \,.$ Since $a\equiv b\mod n$ , we have  :

$$mk+b\equiv b\mod n \implies mk \equiv 0\mod n$$

Since gcd$(m,n) =1$ , we conclude that $k \equiv 0\mod n \implies \color{#3ce}{k =nl}\,.$

Putting this in the original equation , we get $$a = mnl + b \implies \boxed{\color{#2d0}{a\equiv b\mod mn}}$$

Comment: Thats great thank you. Just wondering how you got the mod c on the first line

Comment: @Aaron Well , this is embarrassing  . That was a small typo . Corrected it .

Comment: No problem thanks so much @The Demonix _ Hermit

Answer (score 1):

$ a  \equiv b \mod m $ means $m |(a-b)$

if $ m | (a-b)$ and $n | (a - b)$ then $lcm(m,n)|(a-b)$

since $lcm(m,n)gcd(m,n) = mn$ and $gcd(m,n) = 1$, we have $lcm(m,n) = mn$

so $mn | (a-b)$

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot